# Declare literal union type based on array of objects values

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

Assuming I have an array of objects (simplified version):

```
const arrObj = [
  { id: "example1", other: "just" },
  { id: "example2", other: "an" },
  { id: "example3", other: "example" }
]
```

and I want to create a union type out of all `id`s

I tried:

```
const list = arrObj.map((item) => item.id) as const;
type ids = typeof list[number];
```

But this does not work as it seems I cannot create the array dynamically:

`A 'const' assertions can only be applied to references to enum members, or string, number, boolean, array, or object literals.`

The desired type output should be: `"example1" | "example2" | "example3"`

Comment: Type of the variable, access elements with `number`, then access `id`: `typeof arrObj[number]["id"]`

Comment: @kelly thanks for your comment. I want a literal type union. With that I only get "string".

Comment: Well then, append `as const` to your definition of `arrObj`.

Comment: @kelly thanks, this is working. Fancy doing an answer?

Comment: No, but feel free to upvote and accept the one by Matthieu Riegler.

Answer (score 1):

```
const arrObj = [
  { id: "example1", other: "just" },
  { id: "example2", other: "an" },
  { id: "example3", other: "example" }
] as const

type myIds = typeof arrObj[number]['id']
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQeQEYCsYF4YG0CwAUDDAN4wCWAJgFwwBEApgB5wC2ADgDaMCM9AGhggoAC0YI69dAFdo9GAF8BREuWpSW7bowBMg4WIlS4YBctVlKtBls48AzAZHjJt1vcbmiAXXgQYUEgoIiIoAE8ORhg2cIBJKgCcCKiQADN4JDR0XDAZNlQJH1wAcmoSnwBuIA)